# Raise Error Message

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

In SQL Server 2000, where we don't have SQL Mail set up(for whatever reason) I have a SQL Job that runs the packages on a timer, but even though I have an ActiveX message box in the package it still doesn't raise. I am aware that the message probably does pop up, I don't know where, but I still need to warn the user something as simple as "Package Completed."

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Jobs run under the service `SQL Server Agent`, and services are not allowed to interact with the desktop.

Try going into your list of services (`Start -> Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Services`):

```
Right-click on the SQL Server Agent service -> Properties -> Log On -> 
      Check off "Allow service to interace with desktop".
```

**In general, I'm not sure that having a job interact with the desktop is a good idea.** A better approach may be to set up a task to write a message to the event log, or an entry into the database that it is backing up.